# Is there any way to sent datatypes othern than strings through zeromq pub sub C++?

Tags: c++, string, zeromq, publish-subscribe

I am trying to send an array consist of string, numerical values via zeromq publisher to subscriber.  I am able to send only after typecasting anything to string. Is there any alternate way to sent data other than string?

When i try to send data types without typecasting it results in error.

```
int main () {
    //  Prepare our context and publisher
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t publisher(context, ZMQ_PUB);
    publisher.bind("tcp://*:5563");
int val;
std::string a;
    while (1) {

        a = std::to_string(rand()));

        //  Write two messages, each with an envelope and content
        s_sendmore (publisher, "B");
        s_send (publisher,a);
        sleep (1);
    }
```

result:

```
 error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const string& aka const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&}’ from expression of type ‘char’
         s_send (publisher, char(rand()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Blunt answer: **no**

*ZeroMQ* doesn't encode your data - whatever it may be, you have to do that yourself or use a library like [protocol-buffers](/questions/tagged/protocol-buffers). This is where more full featured RPC libraries like *apache thrift* comes into play as they typical handles some forms of encoding as well as the transmision/multiplexing/etc.